# Suspicious static-linked executable file size

Tags: c, makefile, linker, blackberry-10, qnx

I have a BB 10/QNX app in which I need to use more recent version of SQLite than is default on BB 10. I thought I could do that by linking my own SQLite code with my app. I realized that in my qmake-generated Makefile the option -lsqlite3 is passed to qcc. In the library location (/opt/bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib) I found the following files:

```
size filename
559386 libsqlite3.a
560662 libsqlite3S.a
15 libsqlite3.so -> libsqlite3.so.1
496503 libsqlite3.so.1
```

I thought that I can replace libsqlite3.a with my own file compiled from latest sqlite3.c (amalgamation). What confuses me is that the size of my application executable is just 180 kB, so the code from libsqlite3.a doesn't seem to be present in it. If SQLite is dynamically linked, I'd expect the application archive (.bar) to contain libsqlite3.so, which also isn't true, because the archive is just 130 kB big. How is it possible that the application uses SQLite (via Qt database classes), but SQLite code never makes it to the application archive?

Comment: Compiler will optimize and leave out things that are not needed/used from the static library while building executable. Executable need not always have all code from static library.

Comment: Yes, that the whole idea of an `.a` archive. If the library does that well and has really devided into very small compilation units, the loader really only takes what it needs in the final executable.

Answer (score 0):

**Static version**

When linking an executable to a static library, the compiler know you're building a "finished product": nothing will depend on your executable. It allows the compiler to *not* include unused code. Let's say you're using only one function from the library, which itself is not using anything else from the library. The compiler will pick only the machine code corresponding to this specific function and gently ignore the rest.

**Dynamic version**

Regarding the size of the bar archive and the dynamic library, it goes down to what really is a bar archive. It's simply a zip archive (maybe with some metadata added, don't know in details). Two possibilities: either the .so file is greatly compressed, or the compiler relies on the system library and doesn't bundle it in the bar archive.